# Do Not Check Floating Point Equality/Inequality

Tags: c#

We are using one code analyzer which has a rule like this "Do Not Check Floating Point Equality/Inequality".Below is the example given.

```
float f = 0.100000001f; // 0.1
double d = 0.10000000000000001; // 0.1



  float myNumber = 3.146f;
    if ( myNumber == 3.146f ) //Noncompliant. Because of floating point imprecision, this will be false
    {
      ////
     }
    else
      {
        ////
      }

    if (myNumber <= 3.146f && mNumber >= 3.146f) // Noncompliant indirect equality test
    {
      // ...
    }

    if (myNumber < 4 || myNumber > 4) // Noncompliant indirect inequality test
    {
      // ...
    }
```

when I tested this code if ( myNumber == 3.146f ) is true so I am not able to understand what this rule is trying to say.

What is solution or code change required for this rule?

Is this rule applicable for C#? When I googled I see more examples of C/C++ for this rule

Comment: That's at least a very badly *explained* rule. If you have two identical floating point literals, including suffix, both within a method, I would indeed expect them to be equal.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Precision in Comparison is something we should be aware of, or else things may behave out of excpectation

Comment: In most situations, you may want something like `if (Math.Abs(x - 3.1416f) < 0.0001)` to prevent bugs caused by rounding errors.

Comment: @jetstream96 I have one double and one Int so can I write like this Double test;   Int I;      if(Math.Abs(test-I) < 0.0001)

Comment: @reddy Yes. When you subtract double from int (or vise versa), the int gets casted to double.

Comment: You may want to [read up on floating point](http://blog.reverberate.org/2014/09/what-every-computer-programmer-should.html). One thing is that its precision decreases for larger values. Another thing is that not all floating point values map nicely to a decimal notation. Display routines often use a limited precision, so this isn't always obvious. For example, `0.1f.ToString()` gives you `"0.1"`. However, you can force it to display a higher precision: `0.1f.ToString("G9")`, which gives you `"0.100000001"`.

Comment: @jetstream96 Do you think Math.Abs is not required for double and Int comparision?

Comment: @reddy No, it is required because rounding error still exists.

Comment: @jetstream96 Does the Tolerance (0.0001) vary in different situations?

Comment: @reddy Yes. If rounding error is the only concern, you can use a very small tolerance since `double` has precision of [15 to 16 digits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx). However, sometimes there are other sources of errors. Let's say you use 3.1416 somewhere in your code and Math.PI elsewhere. When you compare the two, the difference is significantly larger than rounding errors.
Choose a tolerance suitable for your situation. For example, when comparing the heights of people, 0.01 centimeter would be quite reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Floating point is not precise. In some cases, the result is unexpected, so it's bad practice to compare floating point number for equality without some tolerance.

It can be demonstrated with simple example.

```
if(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
}
```

It will print `Not Equal`.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ltAFWe

---

The solution is to add some tolerance, for example:

```
if(Math.Abs((0.1 + 0.2) - 0.3) < 0.0001)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Equal");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
}
```

Now it will print `Equal`.

Comment: What is the solution you recommend for this problem?

Comment: @reddy The [documentation `for double.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s(v=vs.110).aspx) gives examples.

Comment: I have one double and one Int so can I write like this Double test;   Int I;      if(Math.Abs(test-I) < 0.0001)

Comment: @reddy Arithmetic operation between `double` and `int` is done in double, the `int` will implicitly converted to double first.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan   double test = 0.5 + 0.5;
            int i= 1;
            if (test == i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Equal");
            }         it gives me Equal result

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan so according to you for double and int Math.Abs is not required...Am I correct?

Comment: @reddy It is still required. It is to make negative number become positive, so you can safely use `<` operator without worry about negative result from subtract operator.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan Does the Tolerance (0.0001) vary in different situations?

Comment: @reddy It depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly readable solution to this is to define an extension method for `double` like so:

```
public static class FloatAndDoubleExt
{
    public static bool IsApproximately(this double self, double other, double within)
    {
        return Math.Abs(self - other) <= within;
    }

    public static bool IsApproximately(this float self, float other, float within)
    {
        return Math.Abs(self - other) <= within;
    }
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
float myNumber = 3.146f;

if (myNumber.IsApproximately(3.146f, within:0.001f))
{
    ////
}
else
{
    ////
}
```

Also see [the documentation for `Double.Equals()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2zha7s(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Comment: @ Mathew Watson Does the Tolerance (0.001) vary in different situations?

Comment: @reddy Yes, you would choose the level of tolerance appropriate for the calculations you're doing. Normally you'd choose something like 0.0000001, but if (for example) you were using data that was only accurate to two decimal places, you might use only 0.005