# Adding then subtracting vector results in vector that is different from starting vector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to move an object up for 60 frames and then move it down for 60 frames, so it should go back to its original place. However, when i tried to do that, thats not what happened. the initial position of the object was (0,1.2,0)  and after i moved it up and down, it backed to the position of (0,1.200001,0). This is the script that i wrote for the object.the object is a 3d cube with a box collider.

```
private float upCounter = 60;
private float downCounter = 60;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (upCounter > 0)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        if (downCounter > 0)
        {
            transform.position -= new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
        }
        downCounter--;
    }
    upCounter--;
}
```

Its important for my project that those position will be precised. 
How can i solve it?
Thanks the helpers anyway.

Comment: Unity represents vectors using floating point numbers. Floats by themselves can't always make exact calculations due to how binary can't represent certain values with complete precision. You need to re-design your project so that it doesn't require that the float values be exactly equal. Why do they need to be exactly equal now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do Not Check Floating Point Equality/Inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420188/do-not-check-floating-point-equality-inequality)

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses floats in its vectors. [If your design requires that you compare floats exactly, you need to change your design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40420188/do-not-check-floating-point-equality-inequality).

### Instead of testing if two floats are exactly equal, use `Mathf.Approximately(f1,f2)`

This checks if they are approximately equal accounting for floating point imprecision.

### If you need to compare two `Vector3`, such as positions, are equal after manipulating them, use `vector1 == vector2`

When you do this, Unity will use `Approximately` on each component to test if they are approximately equal.